# Is it necessary to book a hotel in advance in Baguio, Philippines during May/June?

Tags: hotels, bookings, seasonal, philippines

I am about to make my first trip to Philippines. As it is the low season in most areas, my plan is to travel around the country without a fixed schedule, searching for accommodation on the spot. I'll be aiming to stay in budget hotels, but can afford occasional mid-range accommodation.

I'll be visiting Baguio around the end of May / beginning of June. I understand that during this time the city and surroundings is a popular place for escaping the hottest time of the year. My question is: will there still be plenty of budget accommodation available, or would it be prudent to make a reservation some days beforehand (or even earlier)?

EDIT after 10 days:
I'm still unclear as to the situation with accommodation in Baguio. However, my premise above about this being the hottest time is beginning to look questionable, as weather forecasts predict rain and storms in much of Luzon. To be on the safe size, I will (try to) book the room on the day prior to arriving in Baguio. Will update/answer this question in case that experience gives me some insight on the general availability of rooms.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Usually May is a peak season because of the summer in the Philippines. Many people go to Boracay or Bagiuo. Bagiuo is the best place to go because of the cool area. It is colder than most places in the Philippines.

Should you book a room in advance? Well it depends what you are planning to do and where. Booking in advance gives you usually a better price than being in front of the hotel counter. Especially hotel websites give an instant 10% discount if you in advance. This is their strategy to get hotel rooms booked.

However, the busiest places are the usually the high priced hotels and well located. If you roam around in to the outskirt of the city or keep on searching for pensions you can get a very decent deal. They are usually not well known or they are hardly recognized as a hotel or pension. These places usually have rooms vacant and the price is low. Do not expect too much from these hotels, the standards are usually lower.

If you truly can`t find anything try Sogo Hotel or Mircotel hotel. These hotels are usually cheap but they have a very specific clientel. Not many people want to be seen in this hotel but if you need a place this would be a last option.

For weather details. In June the season is switching from Summer to Rain season. Typhoons are usually common in this season. So be prepared for much rain.

Comment: I marked this answer as accepted, as it was helpful and informative, and was posted already three weeks before I had the opportunity to post my own answer.

Answer (score 1):

Late at evening on May 31st I searched for free rooms in Baguio, for two nights, arrival on June 1st (a Sunday).

Booking.com found 14 hotels having rooms available priced under 50 euros a night.
Agoda.com found about 40 hotels having rooms available priced under 50 euros a night.
These sites together had also at least ten places offering rooms for less than 25 euros a night.

Even based on such a rudimentary search, it seems clear that during the time period referred to in my original question, the city is very far from being packed full of visitors. There is plenty of accomodation to be found for a budget traveler, without needing to book well in advance.

(I wasn't able to log in to travel stackexchange during my trip, so I could only answer now that I'm back)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the latest updated site of Booking.com with 29 hotels that you can choose from within Baguio City.

I was born and raised in Baguio City, so anything you ask about this place I would gladly answer for you. I would suggest to choose a hotel within [Camp John Hay](http://www.campjohnhay.ph/) area. You'll love the scenery and the heavenly aroma of pine trees surrounding you.